# After "import HPGrowingTextView", Xcode could not debug

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, cocoapods

I use `HPGrowingTextView` with cocopods in swift 3.0, but Xcode can not debug alter `import HPGrowingTextView`, and could debug after annotating it.

Comment: what's your platform

Answer (score 0):

Check Legacy Problem.. If HPGrowingTextView is developed in lower version of swift than this error may occur. You can set legacy in build Setting.